# Floating Elevator

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, boundary-conditions, aerodynamics

Balloons can be balanced to have just enough string to be suspended off the floor with the end of the string touching the floor. Another balloon could then also be stacked and top of that balloon in the same manner. **What would prevent airships, other than wind where windless regions do exist on Earth, from being stacked in the same way to support a launching tether?** The tether could provide helium/hydrogen, and electricity. It could work like a electromagnetic catapult found on newer aircraft carriers or provide electricity to a an electric propeller that releases before final launch. **Could this provide much of the lift for spacecraft?** Yes, the blimps would descend during the lift but the overall displacement of air resistance ideally in a stack of pancake shaped doughnuts airships should negotiable to provide lift for the spacecraft and reset back to their extended position after launch.
Feel free to edit!

Comment: For low orbits, the vast majority of the energy of the projectile is the translational kinetic energy required to *keep* it in space, not the gravitational potential energy required to *get* it in space. Working out the ratio for a particular altitude (for instance 200km) would be a pretty good introductory mechanics question.